# How can I autofill author with a model form (video upload)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I need to tie the user to their post but 'author' is not included in the fields of the video upload form so I can't access the field when I save the form.

When I add 'author' to the fields it gives a drop down box. (users shouldn't be able to post as anyone but themselves) I tried just listing the fields individually like so `{{form.title}}` to keep the author field but not show it to the user, it showed anyway.

In the 'author' field of the VideoPost model I've tried changing out the `null=True` for  these variants on default `default=None, default=0, default='None', default=User, default=User.id` where `User = get_user_model()`

When I used `default='None'` the author dropdown box had the current users name in it, but still allowed a choice, when I tried to post it I got 
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'`

Also, in the views.py, I tried `form = VideoPostForm(request.user,request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)`
and got `CustomUser object has no .get() attribute` and that was caused by `form.save()`

I feel like this might be obvious to someone else but I've been staring at this code for a while now to figure it out.(a couple hours a day doing research and gaining better understanding as to how all of the things I'm doing actually work 'under the hood', I worked on other parts while trying to figure this out because, development speed matters and I could actually figure the other stuff out)

forms.py

```
class VideoPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = VideoPost
        fields = ['author','title', 'description', 'file']
```

views.py

```
def upload_video(request):
    form = VideoPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        VideoPost.author = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = VideoPostForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_video.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class VideoPost(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='video_post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    validate_file = FileValidator(max_size=52428800)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', validators=[validate_file])


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Post by {}'.format(self.author)
```

template (excluding author field)

```
<h1>Create Post Page</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p> <!-- Normally the fields would be form.as_p -->
   {{ form.title }}
      {{ form.description }}
      {{ form.file }}</p>
  <button type="submit">Submit New Post</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `views.py` is very close. The [form.save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) returns an instance of VideoPost. You can then set the author to the current user directly to the new video post object that was created by the form. See code sample below.

views.py

```
def upload_video(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VideoPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_videopost = form.save()
            new_videopost.author = request.user
            new_videopost.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = VideoPostForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_video.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: So when we do ```new_videopost = form.save()``` an instance of VideoPost is kind of 'pre saved' then, since we have the model, we can allter the attributes and actually call what we instantiated in ```new_videopost = form.save()``` Is that correct? Thank you this did in fact work, will I need to destroy and rebuild my database for author to be saved in my RSS Feed?

Comment: Yes that is correct. `form.save()` saves the model to the database from the form fields. If you did `form.save(commit=False)` the model would be saved to memory only, and not saved to the database. In which case you would need to call `new_videopoast.save()` in order to persist the new object to the database.